# Which of the following sentences uses a subject complement?

Tags: subjects, complements

[image]

What about C, isn't a bit anxious about the test tomorrow also a subject complement following the linking verb am?

Comment: If I am anxious, I feel nervous. But *am anxious* does not mean that *I* is equal to *anxious*, like *I'm a mess*.

Answer (score 0):

A *subject complement*  is a grammatical entity (*usually a Noun Phrase or an Adjective*) that describes the subject.

The grammatical structure of your sentences is as:

> 1. Subject+Transitive Verb+Object+Adverb

> 2.Subject[NP]+Linking Verb+Subject Complement (*because it describes the Subject*; Note that the Subject Complement here is a Noun Phrase]

> 3.Subject+Linking Verb+Modifier+Adjective+Prepositional Phrase (*PP here is made up of Preposition+Modifier+Noun+Adverb*)

> 4.Subject+Transitive Verb+Object+Object Complement (*Object Complement describes/talks further about the Object*)